# Change icon of codeActivities

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have some code activities.

```
public class baseAct: CodeActivity
{
}
public sealed class C1: baseAct
{
}
public sealed class C2: baseAct
{
}

public sealed class C3: baseAct
{
}
```

**And i use a custom wf desinger.** 
I would like set same icon to activites C1,C2,C3 without define activity designer.

There are something  (AttributeTableBuilder or similar)  to set icon?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a sample that illustrates exactly what you need to do.  [How to create a Custom Activity Designer with Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-9e867448)

Comment: It's works fine! But i have problems when i try to get image from project folder .  With your example               builder.AddCustomAttributes( 
          typeof(MyActivity),  
            new DesignerAttribute(typeof(MyActivityDesigner)),  
            new DescriptionAttribute("My sample activity"),  
            new ToolboxBitmapAttribute(typeof(MyActivity), "Images/QuestionMark.png"));

Comment: Can you please [edit] and add enough detail here that you don't have to go to MSDN in order to get the answer?  We discourage link-only answers and either delete them or convert them to comments. And, while I have your ear--Would you happen to know why the WorkflowItemPresenter requires the WorkflowDesigner's View to be init'd/shown?  I've got some requirements that I fulfill by just showing the root activity designer, which gives me a chromeless design experience, but the WIP doesn't function properly in this scenario. Also, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14693/workflowitempresenter-woes

Comment: OnLoad I register icon: public static void RegisterCodeActivyIcon( Bitmap bm,Type activityDesignerType)
        {
                       AttributeTableBuilder builder = new AttributeTableBuilder();
               
                        builder.AddCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeActivity(, new DesignerAttribute(activityDesignerType));
                AddAtrtibuteTable(builder);
            
        }
  private static void AddAtrtibuteTable(AttributeTableBuilder builder)
        {
            MetadataStore.AddAttributeTable(builder.CreateTable());
        }

Comment: @igor You can put the images inside a project folder and set the BuildAction as Embedded Resource but this will cause the namespace to change to YourNamespace.Images.The toolbox looks for bmp from the default activity namespace so You need to change the namespace for the embedded resource manually , this can be achieved by editing the project file and adding the Logical Name <LogicalName>$(RootNamespace).ToolboxIcon.png</LogicalName>. [More Info on changing embedded namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714389/how-to-change-the-default-namespace-for-embedded-resources-with-msbuild)

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the icon to your solution, set its Build Action to **Resoruce**
2. In your Activity, set the `ActivityDesigner.Icon` to this image

Hardest part about this is getting the Uri right.  If you have problems, just dump the image into the same folder as the designer.

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>
    <DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <ImageDrawing>
                <ImageDrawing.Rect>
                    <Rect
                        Location="0,0"
                        Size="16,16"></Rect>
                </ImageDrawing.Rect>
                <ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
                    <BitmapImage
                        UriSource="RelativeUriToTheImage.bmp" />
                </ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
            </ImageDrawing>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>
```

Comment: Great worked for me just fine. Guys don't you forget point number 1 to add the resource (I did)

Comment: It worked for me when I provided relative image uri as `pack://application:,,,/<Activities.Design.Project>;component/<folder/image.png>`