# How is .NET renaming my embedded resources?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When I build a file as 'embedded resource', Visual Studio gives it a name in the assembly depending on its path in the project. Eg. my file at `cases/2013.1/colours.xml` is given a resource name with sporadic underscores something like `cases._2013._1.colours.xml` .

My question is - how does is this name determined? Are the rules documented? Where is the method that Visual Studio uses?

Edit: I ask because I'm working with a large number of these things and it would be helpful to be able to deduce the resource name from the file path.

Comment: _ is used because an identifier cannot start with a digit (in C# at least).

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3605514/21567), you might just change the name to your liking.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10714391/1354426

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As documented by the MSDN Library article, Resgen.exe uses the rules implemented by the [StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.VerifyResourceName() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145952.aspx).  I'll just copy what the MSDN library says:

> If the key parameter is an empty string (""), a string that consists of a single underscore character (_) is returned. If the key parameter is not an empty string, the VerifyResourceName method compares each character in the string to a set of invalid tokens based on the language specified by the provider parameter. Any invalid character in the string is replaced with an underscore character. The characters that will be replaced with an underscore are as follows:
>
> ' ' (space), U+00A0 (non-breaking space), '.' (period), ',' (comma), ';' (semicolon), '|', '~', '@', '#', '%', '^', '&', '*', '+', '-', '/', '\', '<', '>', '?', '[', ']', '(', ')', '{', '}', '"' (quote), ''' (apostrophe), ':', and '!'.
>
> **Note**
>   Strongly-typed resources do not allow the use of language keywords (such as if, for, and so on) as resource key names. However, the System.CodeDom design pattern allows the use of language keywords by prefixing the keyword with the underscore character. The VerifyResourceName method calls the CreateValidIdentifier method to enforce this design. For example, if you use a resource name that is the same as a language keyword, such as for, the name appears as _for in the generated strongly-typed resource class.

Looking at the source code for the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder class, the documentation is accurate.

Comment: Great! What should I put for the second parameter?

Comment: A CodeDomProvider, just click through the MSDN library link.  You'd use CSharpCodeProvider since you tagged your question [c#].  This is how the method knows about keywords in a language, the part explained in the Note.

Comment: Interestingly I get different results than the name in my assembly when I call StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.VerifyResourceName manually. e.g bundle.config becomes bundle_config but the name in the assembly is bundle.config

Comment: @DavidHayes, you have to apply the algorithm to each identifier component separately.  Split the aggregate identifier string on '.', call `VerifyResourceName` on each part, and then join the escaped parts back together with a '.'.

Comment: Its also worth pointing out that if your resource is inside a folder and that folder starts with a number, then the folder will be prefixed with an underscore as well.

Comment: There seems to be a different treatment for folder name and for file name.  Spaces in folder names are replaced by underscore while space in filenames are preserved. Any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any documentation of how Visual Studio itself generates the names, but I would typically assume that it's compatible with the algorithm used by resgen.exe for standalone builds, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1.aspx).  However, the algorithm described does not work for your example (unless I'm misinterpreting it, it would produce a class name of `cases._013._.colours`), so either VS implements it incorrectly, or the resgen documentation is inaccurate for the specific case you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The simple rules that you can apply to your example are...

```
cases/2013.1/colours.xml
```

1) replace "/" with "."

```
cases.2013.1.colours.xml
```

2) for each item in the dot delimited string, if the item begins with a digit, prepend an underscore to it.

```
cases => cases
2013 => _2013
1 => _1
colours => colours
xml => xml
```

3) reassemble the string, delimited with a dot.

```
cases._2013._1.colours.xml
```

Comment: The reason for this is that the name of the resource has to be compatible with code symbols - so numbers need to have an alphabetical character or underscore added as a prefix to make them valid symbols (variable names). The best approach is to use names that don't need to be changed e.g. "Year2012" rather than "2012". That way, the names will be translated in a very simple way (slashes replaced by dots).