# Embedded resource naming in .NET Core assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

In .NET Framework the compiler automatically renames embedded resources to remove forbidden characters and keywords (see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705211/how-is-net-renaming-my-embedded-resources)). I have noticed that .NET Core does the same thing, e.g. changing dash (-) and other characters to underscores (_) and adding underscores before C# keywords, etc. The problem is that [System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.tools.stronglytypedresourcebuilder?view=netframework-4.8) class is not available on the .NET Core platform. In .NET Framework I'm able to retrieve the modified names in my code through

```
var newResourceName = StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.VerifyResourceName(oldResourceName, new CSharpCodeProvider());
```

As this method is not available for .NET Core, is the only solution available to copy the implementation of VerifyResourceName() and implement it myself? Alternatively I may specify the file names myself in .csproj, but I prefer not to do this as it introduces an additional variable which can be hard to maintain.

Any alternative to these solutions above? Where can I get definitive documentation on which method .NET Core uses to rename my embedded resource files?

Comment: You can get the list of resource names like so:  
var resourceNames = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()

Comment: @DougJohnson I know that. The problem is that dotnet compiler is renaming the resource files when compiling the files into the assembly (due to forbidden characters, e.g. dash (-) and keyword conflicts with the C# language). I need to access this renaming logic so that I can get the actual names in the assembly (e.g. the actual name retrieved from GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())

Comment: I tried this out and didn't run into any character renaming.
I created a new .NET Core Console project and added an embedded resource named _-;',
To display the resources, I used this code: Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()));

The program gave this output:
ResCoreCon._-;',

Comment: @scharnyw did you ever resolve this? I have this same problem: I have some files being loaded as embedded resources and the names are definitely being mangled (.NET Core 3.1, VS2019) - specifically spaces are changed to underscores. Ideally I don't want to hard-code the translation.

Comment: @IanHorwill No. I'm pretty sure the code exists somewhere in the Roslyn code base though, but it's not documented or exposed to the public.