# ReSharper: override default namespace to prevent "Namespace does not correspond to file location"

Tags: c#, resharper

Given two projects:

- Model, assembly "Company.Product.Model", default namespace "Company.Product.Model"
- Model.Server, assembly "Company.Product.Model.Server", default namespace "Company.Product.Model.Server"

As you can see both projects have different default namespaces. It's for sake of resources - both projects has its own resource.resx which will have full names based on project default namespaces.

But both projects have classes related to "model" so I want they to be in the same namespace - "Company.Product.Model". So I use this namespace in both projects.

The problem is that ReSharper requires me to use namespace "Company.Product.Model.Server" for classes in "Model.Server" project as it's default (base) namespace: "Namespace does not correspond to file location...".

I understand it's good by default. But I want to override this - and tell it that all my classes namespaces are based on "Company.Product.Model" without changing project's default namespace.

Is it possible?

Comment: Resharper doesn't force you to change your namespaces. It just advises that you do. Saying that, with most options there is the ability to temporarily disable a given check. Try clicking on the light bulb / spanner that appears when you click on the "erroneous" namespace and you should be able to (in the menu it has) disable the check temporarily.

Comment: "As you can see both projects have different default namespaces. It's for sake of resources". Really? Both should have different namespaces as they are different projects/assemblies. Using the `Company.Product.Model` namespace for classes in `Model.Server` will create confusion for other developers as they won't find the classes in the project they expect them to be in.

Comment: @Pheonyx Sure I can disable warning, but I don't want to.

Answer (score 5):

If you place the selection on one of the folders in the Solution Explorer, then display the Properties tool window, there is an option there called "Namespace Provider". If you set this to `false`, ReSharper will no longer suggest your namespaces should include that folder.

See more info in [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/CheckNamespace.html).

Comment: Yes, but my question is about another thing. I have a project with default namespace "Company.Product.Model.Server" and a class Foo in this project (not in folder) in "Company.Product.Model" namespace. And I want R# to treat such name as correct ("Company.Product.Model.Foo")

Comment: Ah, right. For the root folder, you'd need to change the default namespace in the project properties. However, this would then affect any child folders in the project. Do you want to have a class in the root folder that has a different namespace to other classes in the root folder? And what about other classes in the project - do they use the default namespace? How would you see this working to fit your scenario best?

Comment: I just want to change base namespace for all classes in a project without changing "Default Namespace" option in project settings. I can't change "Default Namespace" because it would affect resx-resources names of that project.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've added a feature request for ReSharper to allow different namespaces in classes in the root of a project. In the meantime, you could take a look [at this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714389/how-to-change-the-default-namespace-for-embedded-resources-with-msbuild) which shows how to specify the namespace for an embedded resource, and not use the default namespace.

Comment: @citizenmatt What I want is to be able to specify the entire namespace for a folder. For example, I'd create a System folder and specify that the entire namespace should be `System` (not `MyAssembly.System`), while keeping the default root namespace `MyAssembly` for all files outside the System folder.

Comment: ReSharper doesn't do this, unfortunately. The best you can do is set the default namespace, and then say whether ReSharper should treat each individual folder as part of the namespace or not.